# for loop not executing asynchronously in parallel code

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, concurrency, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have the following function:

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=None) as executor:
            futures = [executor.submit(execute, row) for row in fetch_row()]
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                # do something
```

According to my understanding `futures` should be populated asynchronously while the for loop executes the futures as they become available.

I've written a print statement right before the `return` in `execute` to make sure that the function is indeed about to return.

It seems that the function is indeed submitting jobs in parallel, and they are returning, but the for loop is not executing **as** the jobs are returning from their respective process, but only after the list is fully built.

I'd like to execute the for at the same time the futures are coming in.

`fetch_row()` is a generator that just reads from a CSV file.

Comment: reading from csv file(s) makes your processes IO bound. Maybe multiprocessing is less efficient in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a list

```
futures = [executor.submit(execute, row) for row in fetch_row()]
```

create a generator (parentheses instead of brackets):

```
futures = (executor.submit(execute, row) for row in fetch_row())
```

Comment: That had no effect, the for loop still doesn't execute until all of the futures are ready.